# How to say web addresses and version numbers in German?

Tags: english-to-german, pronunciation, standard-german

In English, for example, "`http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/ask`" and "Windows 8.1" are read aloud as:

> - H T T P COLON DOUBLE SLASH german DOT stackexchange DOT com SLASH questions SLASH ask
> - Windows eigth POINT one

But how to say in German?

Comment: You don't say »H T T P«. You say »aitch tee tee pee«.

Comment: well, everyone knows how to pronounce H T T P :)

Comment: Yes, everyone knows it, but this is not a contradiction to my statement. Nobody says "h t t p". You write it this way, but you don't say it this way. Everybody says "aitch tee tee pee", and yes, everybody knows that. BUT (and this is important!): In english everybody writes "." and "/" but nobody says "." or "/" (you don't even have phonems for that). You say "dot" and "slash". And this is exactly the core of you question. You asked "how do you say ...". And fact is, you say "aitch" and "tee" instead of "h" and "t".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The URL is:

```
ha te te pe Doppelpunkt Slash Slash german Punkt stackexchange Punkt com Slash question Slash ask
```

Some people say »Schrägstrich« instead of »Slash«.

The software version:

```
Windows acht Punkt eins
```

Comment: Most of the times I use only `Windows acht eins`. I use the version with `Punkt` only, if there could be a misunderstanding, e.g. if there is a Windows 81 (eighty-one).

Comment: "Schrägstrich" is about as commonly used as "Slash", and when there are two slashes instead of "Slash Slash" the most common way to say it would be "Doppelslash", slash is pronounced the same way as in English since it's just an anglicism.

Comment: Google translate says : _Windows acht komma eins_ . Why ?

Comment: @MAKZ: Google kann Dezimalzahlen und Versionsnummern die nur einen Punkt enthalten nicht voneinander unterscheiden. Eine Straße, die im englischen Kontext 8.1 m breit ist, ist in einem deutschen Satz 8,1 m breit. Versionsnummern werden aber auch auf Deutsch mit Punkten geschrieben (und daher auch so gesprochen). Dezimalzahlen haben maximal ein Dezimaltrennzeichen, Versionsnummern können mehrere Punkte enthalten (OSX 10.9.2; Safari 7.0.3; MS Office 14.4.1 usw.)

Comment: had to use GoogleTranslate to understand that .... but, thanks anyway :) German is so interesting

Comment: can i say doppelslash?

Comment: Some "professional URL-spellers" seem to use "Schräger" for the slash (and they would probably say "Auslösen" for "Drücken Sie Return"). Whenever I have to spell URLs via phone, it seems necessary to say "Schrägstrich (der über der sieben, nicht der beim ess-zet)", sigh

Comment: Mit dem richtigen Gesprächspartner kann man auch "... - durch, durch, weh, weh, weh ..." sagen, denn "3/4" spricht man ja auch "drei durch vier" oder kann es so sprechen. Wenn der Gesprächspartner geistig beweglich ist, und man sich oft über Webadressen austauscht, etwa ein Kollege an einem anderen Standort. Zu "t-online" sage ich auch "Teh minus onlein", was vielen erstmal fremd ist, aber dann doch als bequemer als "Teh, Bindestrich, onlein" einleuchtet und gerne adoptiert wird.

Answer (score 3):

Puh... I think it doesn't differs this much:

> Ha Te Te Pe Doppelpunkt[:] Schrägstrich Schrägstrich [//] ... Punkt [.] ....

( just made it little short, but I hope it shows the important things. Inside [] I've put the signs for orientation.)

Comment: would it be incorrect to say _doppelpunkt doppelSchrägstrich_ ?

Comment: No, would be totally fine.

Answer (score 3):

These are often read out on radio /tv progs. I've only ever heard "slash" for "/" (often pronounced in the slightly americanised accent used for many Denglish terms - "slairsh"!)
By the way "www" = "vay vay vay" and I've heard "-" read out  as"minus"

Comment: "www" is not "vay vay vay", you don't speak a "y". In IPA "www" is [veːveːˈveː] (see http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/WWW).

Comment: That's actually one of the few occasions where German is a little more practical than English - having [veːveːveː] with only three syllables, there's no need no to shortcut 'double-u double-u double-u' with 'dub dub dub' as they do e.g. on Australian TV.